# Why are my div colums overrunning and how can I make them flush with their container?

Tags: html, css

I am creating a basic calculator in HTML/CSS without using Bootstrap. There will be four columns of buttons - three mostly for numbers, one for operator buttons (+, -, etc.). The operator buttons column will have five buttons, as opposed to four in the other containers. I want the button divs to all be perfectly flush with each other and with their surrounding container. However, I am running into two problems.

First, when I try to give each column of buttons exactly equal width (25%), the last column appears outside of the box. There is a space between each column and I can't get rid of it.

Second, the boxes vertically run over as well, even though I've set their height to a percentage of the height of their container.

I will get rid of the button borders eventually, but included them here to more easily visually show what is going wrong.

```css
html,
body {
  text-align: center;
  font-family: 'Courier New', Courier, monospace;
}

.mainBody {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 350px;
  height: 350px;
}

.outputWindow {
  width: 100%;
  height: 20%;
  border-bottom: 0px;
  background-color: rgb(164, 174, 177);
  text-align: right;
  line-height: 100px;
}

.buttonsBody {
  width: 100%;
  height: 80%;
  border-top: 0px;
  background-color: rgb(138, 142, 143);
}

.numColumn,
.operatorColumn {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 25%;
  height: 100%;
}

.numButton,
.operatorButton {
  line-height: 50px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.numButton {
  height: 25%;
}

.operatorButton {
  height: 20%;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title>Calculator</title>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css" />
</head>

<body>
  <div class="mainBody">
    <div class="outputWindow">Test </div>
    <div class="buttonsBody">
      <div class="numColumn">
        <div class="numButton">7</div>
        <div class="numButton">4</div>
        <div class="numButton">1</div>
        <div class="numButton">0</div>
      </div>
      <div class="numColumn">
        <div class="numButton">8</div>
        <div class="numButton">5</div>
        <div class="numButton">2</div>
        <div class="numButton">.</div>
      </div>
      <div class="numColumn">
        <div class="numButton">9</div>
        <div class="numButton">6</div>
        <div class="numButton">3</div>
        <div class="numButton">=</div>
      </div>
      <div class="operatorColumn">
        <div class="operatorButton">Del</div>
        <div class="operatorButton">÷</div>
        <div class="operatorButton">x</div>
        <div class="operatorButton">-</div>
        <div class="operatorButton">+</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: exactly the 25% but the border it is not included

Answer (score 0):

Use the overflow: hidden feature shown below

```
.buttonsBody {
  width: 100%;
  height: 80%;
  border-top: 0px;
  background-color: rgb(138, 142, 143);
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

The feature will stop anything leaving your parent div, that way you can resize the parent div to fit what you need in and it will stop things appearing outside

Comment: This is great, but it doesn't get rid of the space between the divs. Any word on that?

Comment: I've slightly tweaked it as i'm not sure what's causing the gap however i've made a modification using the grid layout, it's not perfect but it should get you on the right path you're trying to get

https://codesandbox.io/s/throbbing-dew-4uuw1

Answer (score 0):

I think you can build that layout easily using grid.

[Codesanbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/dank-bash-wpm5t)

basically you can define the columns inside the parent element

```
.buttonsBody {
  border-top: 0px;
  background-color: rgb(138, 142, 143);
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 25% 25% 25% 1fr;
}
```

and try to avoid use

```
  display: inline-block;
```

finally you need to add the box-sizing to avoid the overflow of the boxes

https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_box-sizing.asp

```
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

you can use following approach.Add your own class and write css according to it.If u don't want to use bootstrap u can use css grid it will be easy for u

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Calculator</title>
  <meta charset="UTF-8"/>

   <style>
   html, body {
    text-align: center;
    font-family: 'Courier New', Courier, monospace;
    width:100%;
}

.mainBody {
    display: inline-block;
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
}

.outputWindow {
    height: 20%;
    border-bottom: 0px;
    background-color: rgb(164, 174, 177);
    text-align: right;
    line-height: 100px;
    padding:20px;
}

.buttonsBody {
    border-top: 0px;
    background-color: rgb(138, 142, 143);
}

.numColumn, .operatorColumn {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

.numButton, .operatorButton {
    width:20%;
    float:left;
    line-height: 50px;
    margin:10px;
    border: 1px solid black;
}

.numButton {
    height: 25%;
}

.operatorButton {
    height: 25%;
}
   </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="mainBody">
        <div class="outputWindow">Test </div>
        <div class="buttonsBody">
            <div class="numColumn">
                <div class="numButton">7</div>
                <div class="numButton">8</div>
                <div class="numButton">9</div>
                <div class="numButton">Del</div>
            </div>
            <div class="numColumn">
                <div class="numButton">4</div>
                <div class="numButton">5</div>
                <div class="numButton">6</div>
                <div class="numButton">÷</div>
            </div>
            <div class="numColumn">
                <div class="numButton">1</div>
                <div class="numButton">2</div>
                <div class="numButton">3</div>
                <div class="numButton">x</div>
            </div>
            <div class="operatorColumn">
                <div class="operatorButton">0</div>
                <div class="operatorButton">.</div>
                <div class="operatorButton">=</div>
                <div class="operatorButton">-</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```